# Finding the total time a match was standing in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I have a database that has a table called matchstats which includes a column called time and it is updated each time an action takes place. I also have a column called groundstatsid which when it is not null means the action took place on the ground as opposed to standing. Finally I have a column called Round.

Example:

```
Time | groundstatsid | Round

 1   | NULL          |  1
 8   | NULL          |  1
 15  | NULL          |  1
 18  | 1             |  1
 20  | 1             |  1
 22  | NULL          |  1
 30  | NULL          |  1
 1   | NULL          |  2
```

To get the full time standing I would basically want the query to take the first time (1) and store that, then look at groundstatsid until it sees a NON NULL value and take the time at that position, subtract by the earlier number stored to get the time in standup (17). Then it would continue to look for where groundstatsid IS NULL. Once it finds that value it should do the same process of looking until it finds a NON NULL value in groundstatsid or a new round, in which case it will start the whole process again.

Once it has gone through an entire match I would want it to Sum the results.

I would expect the query of the example to return 25.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would boil this problem down one where you consider pairs of rows, sorted by `time` within each round. PostgreSQL can do this in one pass -- no JOINs, no PL/pgSQL -- using [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html):

```
SELECT
  round,
  first_value(time) OVER pair AS first_time,
  last_value(time) OVER pair AS last_time,
  first_value(groundstatsid IS NULL) OVER pair AS first_is_standing,
  last_value(groundstatsid IS NULL) OVER pair AS last_is_standing
FROM matchstats
WINDOW pair AS (PARTITION BY round ORDER BY time ROWS 1 PRECEDING);
```

This tells PostgreSQL to read the rows from the table (presumably constrained by `WHERE fightid=?` or something), but to consider each `round` separately for windowing operations. Window functions like `first_value` and `last_value` can access the "window", which I specified to be `ORDER BY time ROWS 1 PRECEDING`, meaning the window contains both the current row and the one immediately preceding it in time (if any). Thus, window functions let us directly output values for both the current row and its predecessor.

For the data you provided, this query yields:

```
 round | first_time | last_time | first_is_standing | last_is_standing 
-------+------------+-----------+-------------------+------------------
     1 |          1 |         1 | t                 | t
     1 |          1 |         8 | t                 | t
     1 |          8 |        15 | t                 | t
     1 |         15 |        18 | t                 | f
     1 |         18 |        20 | f                 | f
     1 |         20 |        22 | f                 | t
     1 |         22 |        30 | t                 | t
     2 |          1 |         1 | t                 | t
```

Looking at these results helped me decide what to do next. Based on my understanding of your logic, I conclude that the person should be regarded as standing from time 1..1, 1..8, 8..15, 15..18, not standing from 18..20, not standing from 20..22, and is standing again from 22..30. In other words, we want to sum the difference between `first_time` and `last_time` where `first_is_standing` is true. Turning that back into SQL:

```
SELECT round, SUM(last_time - first_time) AS total_time_standing
FROM (
  SELECT
    round,
    first_value(time) OVER pair AS first_time,
    last_value(time) OVER pair AS last_time,
    first_value(groundstatsid IS NULL) OVER pair AS first_is_standing,
    last_value(groundstatsid IS NULL) OVER pair AS last_is_standing
  FROM matchstats
  WINDOW pair AS (PARTITION BY round ORDER BY time ROWS 1 PRECEDING)
) pairs
WHERE first_is_standing
GROUP BY round;
 round | total_time_standing 
-------+---------------------
     1 |                  25
     2 |                   0
```

You could also get other values from this same inner query, like the total time or the number of falls by using `SUM(CASE WHEN ...)` to count independent conditions:

```
SELECT
  round,
  SUM(CASE WHEN first_is_standing THEN last_time - first_time ELSE 0 END) AS total_time_standing,
  SUM(CASE WHEN first_is_standing AND NOT last_is_standing THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS falls,
  SUM(last_time - first_time) AS total_time
FROM (
  SELECT
    round,
    first_value(time) OVER pair AS first_time,
    last_value(time) OVER pair AS last_time,
    first_value(groundstatsid IS NULL) OVER pair AS first_is_standing,
    last_value(groundstatsid IS NULL) OVER pair AS last_is_standing
  FROM matchstats
  WINDOW pair AS (PARTITION BY round ORDER BY time ROWS 1 PRECEDING)
) pairs
GROUP BY round;

 round | total_time_standing | falls | total_time 
-------+---------------------+-------+------------
     1 |                  25 |     1 |         29
     2 |                   0 |     0 |          0
```

Comment: I ran in to some difficulty with the ROWS 1 PRECEDING and it would appear that it was not usable in 8.4 (which is the DB I am working with). Is there something in 8.4 that could be used instead?

Comment: Sure; I chose `ROWS 1 PRECEDING` with `first`/`last_value` for clarity, but `lag()` is available in 8.4. I wrote up what I believe to be an 8.4-friendly version in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/4090893).

Comment: Would you mind if I talked with you privately? I looked all over for a messaging service (went as far as to look for your site), but was unsuccessful barring twitter. An e-mail or messaging name would be great.

Answer (score 1):

This will calculate standing time for any number of rounds:

```
SELECT round, sum(down_time - up_time) AS standing_time
FROM  (
   SELECT round, grp, standing, min(time) AS up_time
         ,CASE WHEN standing THEN 
             lead(min(time), 1, max(time)) OVER (PARTITION BY round
                                                 ORDER BY min(time))
          ELSE NULL END AS down_time
   FROM  (
      SELECT round, time, groundstatsid IS NULL AS standing
            ,count(groundstatsid) OVER (PARTITION BY round
                                        ORDER BY time) AS grp
      FROM tbl
      ) x
   GROUP BY 1, 2, standing
   ) y
WHERE  standing
GROUP  BY round
ORDER  BY round;
```

[**-> sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/250c9/1)

#### Explain

- Subquery x:

  Exploit the fact that `count()` doesn't count `NULL` values (neither as aggregate nor as window function). Successive rows with "standing" action (`groundstatsid IS NULL`) end up with the same value for `grp`.

  Simplify `groundstatsid` to a boolean var `standing`, for ease of use and elegance.
- Subquery y:

  Aggregate per group - standing time matters. From ground time we only need the first row after each standing phase.

  Take the minimum time per group as `up_time` (standing up)

  Take the `time` from the following row (`lead(min(time) ...`) as `down_time` (going on the ground). Note that you can use aggregated values in a window function:

  `lead(min(time), 1, max(time)) OVER ...` takes the next `min(time)` per round an defaults to `max(time)` of the current row if the round is over (no next row).
- Final SELECT:

  Only take standing time into account: `WHERE  groundstatsid IS NULL`

  `sum(down_time - up_time)` aggregates the total standing time per round.

  Result ordered per round. Voilá.

This makes heavy use of [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html). Needs PostgreSQL 8.4 or later.
You could do the same procedurally in a plpgsql function if performance is your paramount requirement.
Examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13079901/939860) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12502786/939860).